# Python UUID assign most/least significant bits

Tags: java, python, uuid

Java can create a UUID from an [assigned most/least significant 64 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#UUID(long,%20long)). I read through [Python's UUID](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/uuid.html) documentation but could not find a simple way to do that.

I saw you can supply a `fields` argument, but it is split to 6 arguments (3 for most sig bits and 3 for least sig bits). I'm not sure how to split the two arguments I have to fit those six arguments.

So my current Java code is

```
return new UUID((long) str1.hashCode(), (long) str2.hashCode()).toString();
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140892/java-like-function-getleastsignificantbits-getmostsignificantbits-in-python  seem to write function `uuid(mst, lst)`