# PHP equivalent of getLeastSignificantBits() & getMostSignificantBits from Java?

Tags: java, php, uuid, guid

I'm working with UUIDs in PHP and I have to query a database that stores the most significant bits and least significant bits of a UUID in two separate columns. I found [this question for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140892/java-like-function-getleastsignificantbits-getmostsignificantbits-in-python), which seems like exactly what I'd need in PHP, but I don't know how to convert the code, and I've never been great with byte manipulation.

What would the equivalent functions for `getLeastSignificantBits()` and `getMostSignificantBits()` be in PHP? Thanks!

Edit: Example data (if helpful):

```
UUID: b33ac8a9-ae45-4120-bb6e-7537e271808e
```

...should convert to...

```
Upper Bits: -5531888561172430560
Lower Bits: -4940882858296115058
```

Comment: I think you can implement it yourself. Why not?

Comment: @user202729 I explained in the question why I'm having difficulty writing the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need two libraries and *bcmath* extension,
using

`composer require ramsey/uuid moontoast/math`.

Parse UUID using `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid`:

```
$uuid = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::fromString('b33ac8a9-ae45-4120-bb6e-7537e271808e');
echo 'Upper Bits: ' . $uuid->getMostSignificantBits() . "\n";
echo 'Lower Bits: ' . $uuid->getLeastSignificantBits() . "\n";
```

You get:

```
Upper Bits: 12914855512537121056
Lower Bits: 13505861215413436558
```

Using those methods you get `Moontoast\Math\BigNumber` object, so you can get it's value or convert to different bases:

```
$higher = $uuid->getMostSignificantBits();
echo 'Upper Bits 10-base: ' . $higher->getValue() . "\n";
echo 'Upper Bits hex: ' . $higher->convertToBase(16) . "\n";
```

You get:

```
Upper Bits 10-base: 12914855512537121056
Upper Bits hex: b33ac8a9ae454120
```

You can also use `$uuid->getMostSignificantBitsHex()` and `$uuid->getLeastSignificantBitsHex()` which are already converted to hex.

Comment: I'm not able to use Composer for this project. How might I get this library set up without it?

Comment: You can use Composer on local and then just upload files. Other way you can download manually from GitHub and then setup autoloader.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it was the first to correctly answer my question, but a different answer has provided a conversion method with much less overhead which I have given the bounty to.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a library as mentioned in the other answer the code below will work with php versions supporting 64-bit Integers. It is what Java's `UUID.fromString()` method does.

```
<?php
PHP_INT_MAX > 2147483647 or exit("Need php version which supports 64-bit integer\n");

$uuid = $argv[1];
$components = explode("-", $uuid);
count($components) == 5 or exit("$uuid is not a valid UUID\n");

$msb = intval($components[0], 16);
$msb <<= 16;
$msb |= intval($components[1], 16);
$msb <<= 16;
$msb |= intval($components[2], 16);

$lsb = intval($components[3], 16);
$lsb <<= 48;
$lsb |= intval($components[4], 16);

echo "UUID: $uuid\n";
echo "MSB: $msb\n";
echo "LSB: $lsb\n";
?>
```

Example run:

```
~ $ php uuid.php b33ac8a9-ae45-4120-bb6e-7537e271808e
UUID: b33ac8a9-ae45-4120-bb6e-7537e271808e
MSB: -5531888561172430560
LSB: -4940882858296115058
```

Comment: Given the simplicity and small code food print, I am awarding the bounty to you. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This [repo](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/master/src/Uuid.php) may help you.
For most significant bits [this method](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/29fb62b48611761b4c0c4e8f4a428cad19c2b690/src/Uuid.php#L417), and for least significant bits [this method](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/29fb62b48611761b4c0c4e8f4a428cad19c2b690/src/Uuid.php#L397).

Comment: Instead of only linking to resources, you should add relevant code to the SO answer in the event that specific links break or resources are moved in the future.